# Gadget development

Tags: vb.net, winapi, dhtml, windows-vista, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm searching about gadget development when I found this site.
I'd like know if somebody know how get open windows name?

I want get a collection of all the open windows. I know in VB.NET, but dont know in DHTML/VBScript for Windows Vista Sidebar.

If somebody can help me, I'll to stay grateful!
Thanks

Erik

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this specific kind of development, but usually with VB.NET programs you have a deeper access to the operating system resources. Due to security, within DHTML you don't have the same wide set of features.

Hope this helps a bit!